# Cant access discord message C# discord.net

Tags: c#, .net, discord, discord.net

I am trying to access the message from discord via HandleCommand and Socketmessage, but, they cant pass the if check for.

```
public async Task RegisterCommandAsync()
{
   _client.MessageReceived += HandleCommandAsync;
   await _commands.AddModulesAsync(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly(), _services);
}
 
private async Task HandleCommandAsync(SocketMessage arg)
{
   var message = arg as SocketUserMessage;
   if (message.Author.IsBot) return;

   int argPos = 1;

   if (message.HasCharPrefix('!', ref argPos) || 
       message.HasCharPrefix('?', ref argPos))
   {
       Console.WriteLine("win");
   }
}
```

Comment: Debug your code, use breakpoints, inspect the variables and see why it does not pass the `if` check.

Comment: As as i can see, he is receiving message or message.content as "", and not the message that i sent in discord, but he knows when i send the message

Comment: I literally copy pasted the sample with my token from discord.net and did not work

Comment: If your message content is empty, then you didn't enable message intents in the developer portal or you didn't configure it in the DiscordSocketClientConfig (or both)